# VPS vs Dedicated Server - RAM & Processor

Tags: windows, vps, dedicated-server, 1and1

First off, take a look at these two packages. One is a dedicated server package, the other is a VPS:

[Dedicated Server](http://order.1and1.com/xml/order/ServerPremiumDualCoreXL;jsessionid=75369A9A92785A10E81C6F967DBAD8A3.TCpfix141b?__frame=_top&__lf=Static&ordernow=true)
[VPS](http://www.webkeepers.com/windows/vps_ultimateplus.html)

My question is about which will have superior performance. I intend to run multiple somewhat demanding programs at once for extended periods of time.

Am I better off sacrificing the 4GB of RAM to go with the dedicated, or is it safe to use the VPS with 8GB of RAM?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you think you will go over 4 gb of memory get the vps else get the dedicated box. However nothing is mentioned about cpu on the page of the VPS, it's nice to have lots of ram but if you have demanding programs, you might want to get some cpu power. Also, for that price check this out : http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produkte_rootserver/eq4

Comment: Oh wow - can't thank you enough! That offer looks perfect. Thanks again, made my day :)